# Shrine in Rotten's Primal Bonfire room

Tags: dark-souls-2

So I just defeated the Rotten for the first time since the latest update, and now there is a huge glowing shrine behind the primal bonfire.

What is it? What does it want? I just get the feeling it wants to hurt me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the portal to the DLC that will be released on July 22. You can take the portal now, but there's not a whole lot to do in the destination until the DLC is live.

Comment: Crap I gotta do this again. I knew deleting my characters was a poor decision -.-'